# How do I add more than 1 to i every time my for loop runs

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class TxFnd {

public static void main(String [] args){

    int i;
    for(i=75000;i<125001;i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    }
}
```

How do I add more than 1 to `i` every time my for loop runs?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `i++` (which only increments by 1, by definition), use a different assignment in the `for` loop. For example, `i += 7` or `i = i + 23`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the change I have made. Before every iteration, `i increases by 3`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TxFnd {

public static void main(String [] args){

    int i;
    for(i=75000;i<125001;i+=3){
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("");
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!